# ie6 cant select inside of textbox

Tags: html, css, textbox

for some reason in ie6 i can only select a textbox by clicking the border. below is the styling it has:

```
border: 1px solid black;
margin-bottom: 7px;
margin-left: 30px;
padding: 2px;
width: 300px;
```

Comment: Is it a `textarea` or an `input type="text"`?

Comment: There's not enough information to make an assessment.

Comment: This style has nothing to do with the ability to select the text in the box. You also need to post the html code that declares the box. It might be some disabled parameters on it or something.

Answer (score 1):

i have finally solved this. there was some javascript the applied a zindex to the parent that caused this to break. i hard coded a z-index with an !important on it to the textbox and it fixed it.